# How to get a list of Folders and Files in Sharepoint

Tags: python, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

I have started to explore the Graph API, but Sharepoint is quite complicated and I am not sure how to proceed. I previously have worked with OneNote using this API successfully.

Purpose: There are thousands of folders/files and I need to go through the list in order to organize it in a better way. I am looking for a way to export this list into Excel/CSV using Python and Graph API

I want to dynamically get a list of all underlying Folders and files visible from this URL:
https://company1.sharepoint.com/teams/TEAM1/Shared Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx?id=/teams/TEAMS_BI_BI-AVS/Shared Documents/Team Channel1/Folder_Name1&viewid=6fa603f8-82e2-477c-af68-8b3985cfa525

When I open this URL, I see that this folder is part of a private group called PRIVATE_GROUP1 (on the top left).

Looking at some sample API calls [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-list-children?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http):

```
GET /drives/{drive-id}/items/{item-id}/children -> Not sure what drive-id
GET /groups/{group-id}/drive/items/{item-id}/children -> I assume group-id refers to private group. Not sure how to get the ID
GET /sites/{site-id}/drive/items/{item-id}/children -> Assuming site-id is 'company1.sharepoint.com'?
```

For all above not sure what item-id refers to...
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

refer below code. This might help you.

```
https://gist.github.com/keathmilligan/590a981cc629a8ea9b7c3bb64bfcb417
```

Comment: Thanks. Checking it out